# Letting two views being present at the same time with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have two views:

A - a "normal" page.
B - a semitransparent overlay.

I'm trying to get B to be on top of A, i.e. so one can see A in the background through B's semi-transparent overlay.

The issue I'm having is that A disappears when the path for B is entered. Of course, this is normally the correct behaviour (that a new page replaces the old).

How can I let view A persist when B is entered, but otherwise be replaced by new paths?

Currently the Routes look like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/a" component={A} />
  <Route path="/b" component={B} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: How does your Routes look currently. Also which version of react-router do you use

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Updated question.

Comment: that is not the behaviour of react router, as you know. but at the end of the day, they are both just components, and a component can be reused as many times as you want. why not just import A into B, and use some CSS to create the effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple Routes can be rendered with React-router-v4 if their paths overlap like

`/a/b` will also match `/a` and both will get rendered as long as you are not using `Switch` or `exact`, You can configure your Routes like

```
<div>
  <Route path="/a" component={A} />
  <Route path="/a/b" component={B} />
</div>
```

However it entirely possible to have component `B` inside of `A` so that whenever `A` is loaded `B` is also loaded, but I suppose you might want to load `A` independently and hence this solution will not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

In case you dont want to modify routes, I would suggest making root component of every route self sufficient. In order to do that, inside your B component you should also render A. That way you will have better control of what is your view.

A Component be:

```
<A />
```

B Component be:

```
<A>
  <B />
</A>
```

Comment: Note that, this will mean B is always loaded when A is loaded, which might not be what the OP wants

Comment: @Shubham, I didn't get your point. I guess you reversed the components. Do you mean, A is always loaded when B is loaded

Comment: What I mean is that Whenever A is loaded B is loaded. OP might want to just load A without B

Comment: So in that case his A component would render only A. Ok I got you, so I mentioned create two components, one is A and another is B. A contains only A code, whereas B contains A and B's code.